# update specific item at Android GridAdapter

Tags: android, json, gridview

I have an project where devices with Tasmota firmware are sending out MQTT JSON formated messages, that are used in my project to build JSONArray using `.put` method. Later the JSONArray changes are propagated to GridView adapter calling notifyDataSetChanged().

The challenge is to keep JSONArray structure same but with upto date (new MQTT messages arrives) data which arrive in different order then the initial JSONArray structure was. The result is that JSONArray embedded JSONObjects order changes on the fly and the gridView order changes too, that is confusing users. Temporally I tried to solve that by deleting latest JSON message from device that is sending the update from JSONArray by calling `.remove` and the re-adding updated Json Object calling `.put` method + calling notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect changes in the GridView.

```
//on new message arrived
sonoff_obj = mqtt.message;

for(json_position_index = 0; json_position_index < _arr_mqtt.length(); json_position_index++) {
    if (_arr_mqtt.getJSONObject( json_position_index ).getString( "Topic" ).equals( _received_topic )){
        _arr_mqtt.remove( json_position_index );
        _arr_mqtt.put( sonoff_obj );
        break;
    }
}
```

Problem is now, that because using `.put`, then the new JsonObject is always added to last position in the JSONArray, also GridView layout gets reorganised, which confuses end users.

I am looking for solution how to update JsonObject in the JSONArray maintaining same index(position in the Array) or how to directly say the adapter to replace Item at specific position.

So far i can get adapter item content using `.getItem( int index );` but can I tell the adapter something like in (my pseudo code) `.setItem( int index , JsonObject obj)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same challenge, ArrayList is much better choice than JsonArray, because it supports `.set` method which is with `.notifyItemChanged()` method powerful approach to modify specific position in the ArrayList. If you need for some reason to keep JSONArray format (for GridAdapter ie.), you can always export ArrayList into JSONArray like this (and of course call notifyDataSetChanged()):

```
my_mqtt_array = new JSONArray( my_arrayList.toString());
my_mqtt_array.notifyDataSetChanged();
```